# JQuery Toggle icon with a variety of different icons issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass

I am currently trying to set up a menu with a icon toggle, so when one icon is clicked it changes to a cross and then when that cross is clicked it changes back to the original. I have got that far, but when I click a new image I want the old icon to reset and the cross to be applied to the new icon.

This is how far I have got:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
        <a class="collapsed faq-links">
            <i id="icon" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading13">
        <a class="collapsed faq-links">
            <i id="icon" class="fa fa-heartbeat fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>       
</div>
<br />
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
        <a class="collapsed faq-links" >
            <i id="icon" class="fa fa-comments fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.faq-links').click(function(){
    var collapsed=$(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-info-circle');
    $('.faq-links').find('i').removeClass('fa-times');
    $('.faq-links').find('i').addClass('fa-info-circle');
    if(collapsed)
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-info-circle fa-3x fa-times fa-3x')
});
```

I've set up a JSFiddle to show it working  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjiBaird/yycf2jb8/1/

So when I click on info-circle the cross is applied and when I click on another that cross is removed. How do I go about applying this so every icon.

Any help would be appreciated, hope I made myself clear.

Comment: you should not use `id="icon"` many times.

Comment: @Banzay Good spot, didn't even see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a data attribute to the anchor tags with the specific icon class name like so

```
<a class="collapsed faq-links" data-icon-name="fa-info-circle">
  <i id="icon" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x"></i>
</a>
```

You can use that attribute to toggle the icons between the 'fa-times' and the original one

Have a look at the code below and the JSFiddle to see how it works. Also there are inefficiencies in the code namely in the constantly using `.find('i')` but i'll leave it up to you to come up with a solution for that.

```
$('.faq-links').click(function() {
  if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-times')) { //then change back to the original one
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass($(this).data('icon-name'));
  } else {
    $('.faq-links').each(function(){ //Remove the cross from all other icons
        if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-times')) {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass($(this).data('icon-name'));
      }
    });
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-times').removeClass($(this).data('icon-name'));
  }
});
```

The Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yycf2jb8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the "cross" icon classes from all buttons, then reset all buttons to their default icon and finally draw the "cross" (if needed) for the current one. Like this:

```
$('.faq-links').click(function(){
        var notCollapsed = $(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-times');              

        //Remove crosses from all buttons
        $('.faq-links').find('i').removeClass('fa-times');          

        //Reset the default icon for each button 
        $('.faq-links:eq(0)').find('i').addClass('fa-info-circle');
        $('.faq-links:eq(1)').find('i').addClass('fa-heartbeat');
        $('.faq-links:eq(2)').find('i').addClass('fa-comments');

        //Draw the cross if needed
        if(!notCollapsed) $(this).find('i').attr("class",'fa fa-times fa-3x');
});
```

See your update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/yycf2jb8/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to ensure that the class fa-times takes precedence over the fa-heartbeat, fa-info-circle and fa-comments classes this simple code would work just fine.

```
$('.faq-links').click(function() {
  var blockI = $(this).find('i');
  if(blockI.hasClass('fa-times')) {
    // remove fa-times class if the element already has it
    blockI.removeClass('fa-times');
  }
  else {
    // clean the classes from other elements that might have it
    $('.faq-links i').removeClass('fa-times');
    // adds it on the clicked element
    blockI.addClass('fa-times');
  }
});
```

You can redefine class fa-times in a later css file or style block and/or using a more specific selector to redefine the class so that fa-times style "overrides" the other classes. That would be the best for me because you dont need to mess around with the other classes. You can modify the order of the links or add news ones and the script would still work.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<i id="icon" class="fa fa-heartbeat fa-3x" data-icon="fa-heartbeat"></i>
```

About HTML:

For storing the icon name, the best way would be using [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).
It is easy to understand + you will have no problem with changing it in the future. Make sure, you use `id` attribute only for one `DOM Element`, for multiple elements, use `class` attribute.

JS:

```
// jQuery safety
(function($) {

  // DOM ready
  $(function() {

    // icons
    var $icons = $('.faq-links');
    $icons.on('click', function(e) {

      // variables
      var $this = $(this);
      var $icon = $this.find('i');

      // iconName taken from data-icon attribute
      var iconName = $icon.data('icon');

      // close icon
      var closeIconName = 'fa-times';

      // prevent default browser behaviour, just in case
      e.preventDefault();

      // handle state
      if ($icon.hasClass(closeIconName)) {
        $icon.removeClass(closeIconName).addClass(iconName);
      } else {
        $icon.addClass(closeIconName).removeClass(iconName);
      };
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

About JS:

I believe in clean code writing. The cleaner, the better - stick with that in your coding adventure.
First, we take `$icons` - every icon we have.
We are waiting for `click` event.
Once one of the `$icons` is clicked, we set `$this` as the clicked icon. We also set `$icon` as `<i></i>` element inside clicked icon, just for cleaner code.

`iconName` is equal to icon's data-attribute, so we can use it easily in further steps.

Now we have `// handle state` section. It is simple to understand, that if the `$icon` has class, which is equal to `closeIconName` (cross in this example), it is 'active'. So once this 'active' icon is clicked, we remove 'active' state, which means, we remove `closeIconName` class and we add `iconName` which is the default icon name (took from data-attribute). If the icon isn't 'active', we remove the icon and we add `closeIconName` icon.

NOTE: icon without data-attribute simply doesn't change to fa-close icon.

EDIT: here is JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fy2po3b/1/